# How can I ensure only one port/disk is booted (attempted to be booted) from?

Tags: motherboard, bios, sata

I have a new motherboard (Jetway NF98), and unlike prior BIOS/boards I have had, I am unable to garuntee a boot priority list and lock the BIOS out.

#### Goal

Ensure only one disk/port is booted from.

#### Issue

BIOS has dynamic boot priority list; depending on what is connected and at what time, the list can automatically change.

Does anybody know a way to achieve this?

I do not want all the other disk ports completely disabled (read: post boot) but I do not want the system to try and boot from any other disk besides the one I configure it to.

Comment: Awesome. Another name for my "Do Not Buy" list.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Too bad everything else about the board makes it perfect for my purposes.

Comment: Physically disconnect all the rest?